# Administrator Angular Dashboard What do I need

Tags: node.js, angular, dashboard

After I figured that my other question is way too complex ([Angular Creating a drag and drop editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282184/angular-creating-a-drag-and-drop-editor)) I am thinking about a second project to begin with. This again kind of complex, but I hope that I get a kick start here.

I am planning to make a Dashboard for my home. This dashboard should be able to show different widgets (todo, calendar etc) and should have a route to a website showing my Homeserver.

This dashboard should have an admin page accessible via localhost/admin (no login). On this page one should be able to define the layout, i.e. placing the widgets via drag and drop.

Now while placing something via drag and drop shouldn’t be too hard I am struggling with to things:
 - How can I place one or multiple things via drag and drop that has functionality in it?
 - How can I create a page using an admin page that can be showed by a normal page?

The whole thing should run on a nodejs Server on CentOS in docker.

Maybe someone can give me a kick start on what packages I need. Besides Angular, Node, Angular Material, Drag and Drop ... ;)

Thanks!

Comment: You can start by searching admin bootstraps that are capable of drag and drop and you can do the rest.

Comment: This is way too broad. I'm not even sure what you're asking. Start small. Do something minimal. Then add features one by one, small step by small step. Split the big problem in several smaller incremental tasks.

Comment: Of course i am starting small. However when i know all the Bits and pieces i can start going one step after another. There should be a Page (Admin area) in which i can Setup what should actually be shown. Setup should be via drag and drop. The Elements, lets Call them Widgets, should be able to carry functionality, e.g. API to Google calendar. I think it could be easier to add Login functionality, because then i can guard the edit function and End Up with only one Page. But so far i didnt Unserstand how to add functiinal Elements via drag and drop. (different Phone with Bad Auto correcr)

Comment: You will know when you start reading and experimenting with drag and drop. You learn by doing. Not by trying to plan everything in advance. https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: I will of course. Also found this https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/drag-and-drop-dashboard-builder-with-angular-and-gridster-a07592e54ce2